# Create a simple interface for users to build dialogs in Bot Framework V4

Tags: c#, botframework

Hi i want to build a simple webapp UI for user to build bots like ChatFuel but simpler. Will probably use angular for web app front end and c# bot framework. Is it possible to do this using bot framework? Do i need to learn direct line in bot framework?

What knowledge do i need in order to build an app like that and to be able to run it in messenger or other channels.

I have knowledge building bots using bot framework and publishing it to Azure Bot Service and Facebook messenger. Thanks!

Comment: The [Bot Framework Composer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer) has been announced and is in preview.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not familiar with ChatFuel, but I get the general idea. Are you wanting to build the entire bot? Or just the dialogs? Just C#?

If you just want to build dialogs, I would take a look at [Declarative dialogs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/adaptive-dialog/declarative). This is still in experimental phase, not to be used in production, but if it does make it to release; it would likely be the easiest route.

> Is it possible to do this using bot framework?

Well, not simply. I guess I would say it *is* possible, just how much effort you want to put in and how complex you want it to be able to get. If you just wanted to build something that would then output dialogs, etc to a C# class, along with maybe snippets to put in the bot; that would be somewhat straightforward. (user would then take the output from your tool and copy into the project. If you're wanting to end up with a fully functioning bot, that of course will take much more work.

> Do i need to learn direct line in bot framework?

No, shouldn't be needed.